# Programmatically create binding expression

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a scenario where an expression I wish to execute is dynamically loaded into a component. I am unable to set the expression into `v-if` as it is a literal string, not the actual binding expression.

I had a look at using `vm.$watch` however the expressions are only allowed to be dot notation paths, rather than single javascript expressions.

> `vm.$watch` usage: Watch an expression or a computed function on the Vue instance for changes. The callback gets called with the new value and the old value. The expression only accepts simple dot-delimited paths. For more complex expression, use a function instead.

Is there some part of vuejs that I can use to achieve this? I assume that the binding expressions for the `v-if` directive etc are ultimately strings that are being parsed and evaluated in a given context, it just just whether these functions are available for use in components?

Hopefully this example below shows a more complete picture of what I am trying to achieve:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="expression"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'mycomponent'
    data: function() {
      var1: 5,
      var2: 7,
      expression: null
    },
    created: function() {
      this.$http.get('...').then((response) => {
        // Sample response:
        // {
        //   'expression' : 'var1 > var2'
        // }
        // TODO: Not this!!
        this.expression= response.expression;
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tidying up a question I have left open for over a year, the answer I have ended up using is to use the Angular Expression library [Angular Expressions](https://github.com/peerigon/angular-expressions) for my purposes, but will likely be moving to using the [Friendly Enough Expression Language](https://github.com/EdgeVerve/feel) library in future as both my client and server will evaluate similar expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a *method* for this, e.g. :

```
<div v-if="testExpression"></div>
```

And add *methods* in your component config :

```
methods: {
    testExpression() {
        return eval(this.expression)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am trying (as mentioned by @roy-j below) to avoid using eval as it is _quote: Not Generally Good JavaScript_. For the time being I have decided to use [link](https://github.com/peerigon/angular-expressions) which provides a degree of safety (albeit not bullet proof, I think probably an improvement over eval).

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that evaluating expressions requires you to use things that are Not Generally Good JavaScript, such as `eval` and `with`. Take care to ensure that you control what can get in to any use of `eval`.

I recommend using a `computed` rather than a method for this; it seems more well-suited (and avoids requiring invocation parentheses).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    var1: 5,
    var2: 7,
    expression: null
  },
  computed: {
    evaluatedExpression: function() {
      with(this) {
        try {
          return eval(expression);
        } catch (e) {
          console.warn('Eval', expression, e);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.expression = 'var1 < var2';
    }, 800);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.expression = 'var1 > var2';
    }, 2500);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{expression}}, {{evaluatedExpression}}
  <div v-if="evaluatedExpression">
    Yep
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    Nope
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the example. As commented on @soju's post, i am trying to avoid using eval to achieve this, so for the time being am using [link](https://github.com/peerigon/angular-expressions).